# AngularJS 1.5.9 | Component Event not passing data when run on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs

The child component gets the data from a service, and as soon as the data is received it dispatches an event to the parent component:

```
vm.onButtonClicked({
   item: item,
   items: vm.items
});
```

vm.items is an array of objects and it does exist up to this point, so I'm correctly sending it.

This is the parent component's template code:

```
<child on-button-clicked="onButtonClicked(item, items)"></child>
```

And this is how I receive the event in the parent's component code:

```
$scope.onButtonClicked = function (item, items) {
    $scope.selectedItem = item;
    $scope.items = items;
};
```

The bug occurs here. If I test it on my laptop's browser (Chrome, Safari and Firefox), I'm getting the items array, but if I test it on an iOS simulator (it happens on ios and android devices as well) the item object is received, but the items array is undefined. It's weird how I get the item object, but not the items array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error. There's been another HTML for mobile devices and I haven't included the second argument "items" in the event handler.

```
<child on-button-clicked="onButtonClicked(item)"></child>
```